# Searching a text file c#

Tags: c#, search

I am making an application which saves and loads information about products. These products have a product name, customer name and a firmware location. I have got them to save and load correctly, however I am now trying to find a way where I can search for a product on its name. 
Here is my products class:

```
    //private product data
    private string productName;

    public string getProductName()
    {
        return this.productName;
    }

    public void setProductName (string inProductName)
    {
        this.productName = inProductName;
    }

    private string customerName;

    public string getCustomerName()
    {
        return this.customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName (string inCustomerName)
    {
        this.customerName = inCustomerName;
    }

    private string firmwareLocation;

    public string getFirmwareLocation()
    {
        return this.firmwareLocation;
    }

    public void setFirmwareLocation (string inFirmwareLocation)
    {
        this.firmwareLocation = inFirmwareLocation;
    }


    //constructor 
    public Product (string inProductName, string inCustomerName, string inFirmwareLocation)
    {
        productName = inProductName;
        customerName = inCustomerName;
        firmwareLocation = inFirmwareLocation;
    }


    //save method
    public void Save (System.IO.TextWriter textOut)
    {
        textOut.WriteLine(productName);
        textOut.WriteLine(customerName);
        textOut.WriteLine(firmwareLocation);
    }

    public bool Save(string filename)
    {
        System.IO.TextWriter textOut = null;
        try
        {
            textOut = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename, true);
            Save(textOut);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (textOut != null)
            {
                textOut.Close();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static Product Load (System.IO.TextReader textIn)
    {
        Product result = null;

        try
        {
            string productName = textIn.ReadLine();
            string customerName = textIn.ReadLine();
            string firmwareLocation = textIn.ReadLine();
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        return result;
    }


}
```

}

I was wondering how I would search through the file say search a product name, and it would find it and display the product name, customer name and firmware location

Comment: You didn't ask a question! Note my downvote, but maybe improve this before your rep gets slaughtered.

Comment: Does your Load method always return null or am i not seeing well today ?

Comment: Deserialize your textfile to an object/class in memory, and you can perform a LINQ query against it.  You have not shown what you have done or tried.

Comment: No the save and load method is fine, I was wondering how I would search through the file say search a product name, and it would find it and display the product name, customer name and firmware location

Comment: Depends a lot on how much data you have - why not store it in a database if you need to search and use it later?

Comment: There shouldn't be too much data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firstly, some recommendations for your current class...**

The `Save` function is exceptionally poor for pulling out data from the file again. Do this instead:

```
public class Product {
    // Note that I've added a constructor for this class - this'll help later
    public Product(string productName, string customerName, string firmwareLocation) {
        this.productName = productName;
        this.customerName = customerName;
        this.firmwareLocation = firmwareLocation;
    }

    public void Save (System.IO.TextWriter textOut)
    {
        textOut.WriteLine(String.Format(
            "{0},{1},{2}", this.productName, this.customerName, this.firmwareLocation);
    }
}
```

So instead of getting this:

```
...
Awesome Hairdryer
Nick Bull
C://hair.firmware
Awesome TV
Nick Bull
C://tv.firmware
...
```

you get this:

```
...
Awesome Hairdryer,Nick Bull,C://hair.firmware
Awesome TV,Nick Bull,C://tv.firmware
...
```

**Once you've done that...**

It's a really easy question. One liner, with some examples of methods used as filters for "searching", if you want them:

```
IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(pathToTextFile)
    .TakeWhile(line => line.Contains("Nick Bull"));
```

**EDIT**: Even neater one-liner, returning a `Product` collection:

```
List<Product> lines = File.ReadLines(pathToTextFile)
    .TakeWhile(line => line.Contains("Nick Bull"))
    .Select(line => new Product(line.Split(',')[0], line.Split(',')[1], line.Split(',')[2])
    .ToList();
```

To iterate through them and do other more complicated stuff, you could read them all then do stuff:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
var products = new List<Product>();

foreach (string line in lines) {
    if (Regex.IsMatch(line, @"super awesome regex")) {
        string[] lineItems = line.Split(','); // Splits line at commas into array
        products.Add(new Product(line[0], line[1], line[2]); // Thanks to our constructor
    }
}

foreach (var product in products) {
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Product name: {0}", product.productName));
}
```

**Search functionality update**

To search, use these functions:

```
public enum ProductProperty {
    ProductName,
    CustomerName,
    FirmwareLocation
}

List<Product> GetAllProductsFromFile(string filePath) {
    if (!File.Exists(filePath)) throw FileNotFoundException("Couldn't find " + filePath);

    return File.ReadLines(filePath)
       .Select(line => new Product(line.Split(',')[0], line.Split(',')[1], line.Split(',')[2])
        .ToList();
}

function SearchProductsByProperty(IEnumerable<Product> products, ProductProperty productProperty, string value) {
    return products.ToList().Where(product => 
        (productProperty == ProductProperty.ProductName) ? product.productName == productName :
        (productProperty == ProductProperty.CustomerName) ? product.customerName == customerName :
        (productProperty == ProductProperty.FirmwareName) ? product.firmwareName == firmwareName : throw new NotImplementedException("ProductProperty must be ProductProperty.ProductName, ProductProperty.CustomerName or ProductProperty.FirmwareName");
    );
}
```

Then:

```
var products = GetAllProductsFromFile(filePath);
var searchedProducts = SearchProductsByProperty(products, ProductProperty.ProductName, "Awesome TV");

foreach (var product in searchedProducts) {
    // Each product will have a `ProductName` equal to "Awesome TV".
    // Finally, get the customer name by doing this within this foreach loop, using `product.customerName`
    Console.WriteLine(product.customerName);
}
```

Comment: I have googled it, I have an idea how to find the product name but I need to be able to display the correct customer name and firmware location that goes with it

Comment: @lucycopp Then you'd know that this answer allows you to get all lines into an array, optionally search each line (using `.TakeWhile(line => line.Contains("I want the line to contains this"))`), and then you'd have all the data on that line ready to search and parse!

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful, is there a way so I could search the name and it would tell me the firmware location, because eventually that'll be what I'll be using it for, so the user can type in what product they want and the correct firmware will be located

Comment: @lucycopp One more edit - you can use that last function to search: first, get the list of products to a variable using `GetProductsFromFile`, then search that list using `SearchProductsByProperty(productsList, ProductProperty, "value")`, where `ProductProperty` is one of these three: `ProductProperty.CustomerName`, `ProductProperty.ProductName` or `ProductProperty.FirmwareLocation` (i.e., `ProductProperty.`, then any of the values in the `public enum` in the code in the answer). The final value will be searched against whichever `ProductProperty` you chose as a variable for the function call.

Comment: Thank you, would I put the enum bit in the class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120234/discussion-between-nick-bull-and-lucycopp).