# Search Method through text file c#

Tags: c#, wpf, search

I have made an application which saves and loads data from a text file. What I want to do is search for a string, display that string as well as the two strings after in the appropriate places of the WPF.
I think it is finding the string okay because the counter is displaying correctly however none of the strings are displaying. Here is my search method:

```
   public void Search(string searchTerm)
    {
        var lineCount = File.ReadLines("products.txt").Count();
        string line;
        int counter = 0;


        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("products.txt");

        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains(searchTerm))
            { 

                break;
            }

            counter++;
        }

        textBlock.Text = counter.ToString();

        string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines("products.txt");

        allLines[counter] = productNameBlock.Text;
        allLines[counter + 1] = customerNameBlock.Text;
        allLines[counter + 2] = firmwareBlock.Text;


    }
```

any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like products.txt should be in a structured format like XML (or SQLite) which is designed to make it easy to lookup/change/save data without having to walk all over a text file.

Comment: You're reading all of the lines in the file at least 3 times - why? It's very inefficient. You should only do this once.

Comment: ah thats annoying!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you flipped the assignment:

```
productNameBlock.Text = allLines[counter];
customerNameBlock.Text = allLines[counter + 1];
firmwareBlock.Text = allLines[counter + 2];
```

Second, you're not using `lineCount` so just remove that extra reading line.

Comment: No, but I think you missed your daily coffee.

Comment: definitely! hahaha

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't you use the search function I provided you in [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38787000/searching-a-text-file-c-sharp/38787062#38787062)? Could have done this easily. Anyway...

```
   public void Search(string searchTerm)
    {
        var allLines = File.ReadAllLines("products.txt");
        int nonMatchingLineCount = allLines.Where(line => !line.Contains(searchTerm)).Count();

        textBlock.Text = nonMatchingLines.Count().ToString();

        productNameBlock.Text = allLines[counter];
        customerNameBlock.Text = allLines[counter + 1];
        firmwareBlock.Text = allLines[counter + 2];
    }
```

Comment: hi i tried to yours method and i kept getting errors for some reason, i sent you a message about it.

Comment: thank you for all your help tho its been a massive help!

Comment: @lucycopp No worries, my apologies! Doesn't seem that chats send notifications :(

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have this reversed

```
allLines[counter] = productNameBlock.Text;
allLines[counter + 1] = customerNameBlock.Text;
allLines[counter + 2] = firmwareBlock.Text;
```

What if you did this instead?

```
productNameBlock.Text = allLines[counter];
customerNameBlock.Text = allLines[counter + 1];
firmwareBlock.Text = allLines[counter + 2];
```